# Here API QPS (Queries per second)

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to find the QPS for the Here API and if there is a difference between freemium and Pro.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get details on the limits for Freemium and pro, number of supported queries and billing information on our FAQs page:

https://developer.here.com/faqs#general

We do not specify a hard limit on queries per second, you might experience delays if there are too many requests than the platform can handle.

Note however that:
**Both the Production and CIT environments are not designed to support sudden, unannounced high loads. If you need to do performance testing, contact HERE to discuss options.**

Please contact Sales if you require custom package:
https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you

Comment: Sorry I still don't see QPS listed.  For instance with Azure free has a limit of 50 QPS and paid has no limit.  I'm just checking to see if Here has any such limit.